# clearInterval not working in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` in a React functional component. I am incrementing the count inside the `setInterval` and want to `clearInterval` once it has reached certain value.but it is not clearing out, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [chartsCount, setChartsCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartsCountId = setInterval(() => {
      setChartsCount((count) => {
        console.log('set chart count function is running ', { chartsCount });
        if (chartsCount >= 3/*16*/) {
          console.log('We have reached the limit');
          clearInterval(chartsCountId);
        }
        return count + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(chartsCountId);
    };
  }, [chartsCount]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've made `chartsCount` a dependency on the `useEffect`, so every time it changes one interval is canceled and another is started. That *includes* when the count has gone above the limit, since you're still adding to the count in that case.

Instead:

1. Don't make `chartsCount` a dependency of the effect, and
2. Use `count` (the parameter if your `setChartsCount` callback) rather than `chartsCount` in your effect code

Updated snippet, see the four comments with `***`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [chartsCount, setChartsCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartsCountId = setInterval(() => {
      setChartsCount((count) => {
        console.log('set chart count function is running ', { chartsCount: count }); // ***
        if (count >= 3/*16*/) { // ***
          console.log('We have reached the limit');
          clearInterval(chartsCountId);
          return count; // *** >>IF<< you don't want count incremented the last time
        }
        return count + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(chartsCountId);
    };
  }, []); // ***
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the logic outside the setState, since you are including the `count` in the deps of the effect you don't need to read the fresh state in a callback:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [chartsCount, setChartsCount] = useState(1);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const chartsCountId = setInterval(() => {
      if (chartsCount >= 3 /*16*/ ) { // ***
        console.log('We have reached the limit');
        clearInterval(chartsCountId);
      } else {
        setChartsCount(c => c + 1);
        console.log("Current count: ", chartsCount )
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(chartsCountId);
    };
  }, [chartsCount]); // ***
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Or if you want just a simple and quick fix to your code:

```
 setChartsCount((count) => {
        console.log('set chart count function is running ', { chartsCount });
        if (chartsCount >= 3/*16*/) {
          console.log('We have reached the limit');
          clearInterval(chartsCountId);
          return count
        }
         return count + 1;
      });
```

Basically you are setting the same count if you reach the limit, and that will prevent the effect from running again.